# Заполнить поля класса из строки

Tags: c#

Имеем следующий класс:

```
public enum SomeEnum { SomeOne, SomeTwo, SomeThree }
    
public class Identificator
{
        public int i;
        public string s;
        public SomeEnum e;

        public Identificator() { }
        public Identificator(int i, string s, SomeEnum e)
        {
            this.i = i;
            this.s = s;
            this.e = e;
        }
        
        public override string ToString() => string.Join(".", i, s, e);

        public static Identificator GetIdentificator(string text)
        {
            Identificator id = new ();
            var split = text.Split(".");
            id.i = Int32.Parse(split[0]);
            id.s = split[1];
            Enum.TryParse(split[2], out id.e);
            
            return id;
        }
}
```

По условиям задачи поля класса преобразуются в строку конкатенацией через определенный заранее разделитель (в нашем случае ".". Имеется необходимость в обратном преобразовании - из строки получить экземпляр класса. Для этого реализован статический метод GetIdentificator:
C#

```
public static Identificator GetIdentificator(string text)
{
            Identificator id = new ();
            var split = text.Split(".");
            id.i = Int32.Parse(split[0]);
            id.s = split[1];
            Enum.TryParse(split[2], out id.e);
            
            return id;
 }
```

Метод GetIdentificator получился страшненьким. Кроме того, при изменении класса Identificator (добавление поля, например) необходимо переписывать GetIdentificator.
Уважаемые знатоки, как переписать метод GetIdentificator красивее/функциональнее?

Comment: Добавьте в текст вопроса пример формата строки из которой нужно получить значения. И вообще, формат строки может быть изменен например на `FieldName1=FieldValue.FieldNameN=FieldValueN`? Если да, то можно через рефлексию всё оформить по красоте

Comment: У вас, по сути, получаеться формат `csv`, где в качестве разделителя выступает точка. Просто погуглите `NuGet`-пакеты, которые позволяют сериализировать и десериализировать `csv`. [Пример с библиотекой `CsvHelper`](https://siddarthkanted.wordpress.com/2018/02/14/c-deserialize-tsv-or-csv-file/)

Comment: @Aarnihauta, в качестве примера: "1.SomeText.SomeOne". Внести в формат строки имена полей класса, к сожалению, низя.